# date-fns format(fromUnixTime(1584161862798), 'yyyyMMdd') invalid time value

Tags: date-fns

I am using date-funs library to manage dates. 
( version 2.12.0 )
I need to format unix datetime to 'yyyyMMdd'.
And I am getting 'invalid time value' error.

```
fromUnixTime(1584161862798) 
// Sat Feb 03 52170 22:13:34 GMT+0900 (대한민국 표준시)

format(startDate, 'yyyyMMdd');
// invalid time value
```

I am nor sure why this is not working, when

```
format(new Date(), 'yyyyMMdd')
// 20200413
```

this works.

I tried to parse the date. It still returns the same error.

```
format(parseISO(startDate), 'yyyyMMdd');
// invalid time value
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
format(new Date('yourUnixDateTime'), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Answer (score 12):

Another answer on here is close but here's what worked for me:

`format(new Date('yourUnixDateTime' * 1000), 'yyyyMMdd')`

Comment: why we should multiply the timestamp by 1000 ?

Comment: Php give titestamps as timestapm/1000.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanGad 1 You need to multiply the timestamp by a factor of 1000, because JS timestamps are kept in milliseconds as opposed to Unix timestamps which use seconds.